# Counting the Number of Events Currently Elapsing When a New Event Occurs (RevoScaleR/mrsdeploy)

Tags: r, sql-server-2016

Here is some Example Data:

```
Begin = c("10-10-2010 12:15:35", "10-10-2010 12:20:52", "10-10-2010 12:23:45", "10-10-2010 12:25:01", "10-10-2010 12:30:29")

End = c("10-10-2010 12:24:23", "10-10-2010 12:23:30", "10-10-2010 12:45:15", "10-10-2010 12:32:11", "10-10-2010 12:45:05")

df = data.frame(Begin, End)
```

I want to count the number of events that have not currently finished when a new event begins and record it in a new column. So for this particular example the end result that is desired would be a column with values: 0, 1, 1, 1, 2

I have a solution on how to do this with data.table and it worked fine. I would like to be able to find a solution that works in the RevoScaleR/mrsdeploy packages so the program that does this can take advantage of parallel computing/data chunking.

Here is the solution that works in data.table:

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, dmy_hms))
dt <- as.data.table(df)
setkey(dt,Begin,End)[,id:=.I]
merge(dt, foverlaps(dt,dt)[id>i.id,.N,by="Begin,End"], all.x=T)[,id:=NULL][is.na(N),N:=0][]
```

Again, I am looking for one that can be executed remotely on SQLSERVER2016 with the packages mentioned.

Comment: I'm counting the number of events that have not ended yet when another one begins. This is power outage data so this is saying 'when this power outage began, there were already x amount of power outages that had not been repaired yet'.

Answer (score 0):

Process begin and end in ascending order, and keep a count of how many begins and ends you have seen. If you don't have duplicate/spurious end events, this will work just fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it with a simple `sapply`

```
sapply(df$Begin, function(x) sum((x < df$End) & (x > df$Begin)))
```

To parallelize it just use `rxExec`, `mclapply`, `parLapply`, `foreach`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this in t-sql that was the quickest way. That information is located here: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/intervals-and-counts-part-1

It could also be translated to R easily for anyone doing this in the future. I chose to just complete the operation in t-sql though.